# Android view jfeinstein SlidingMenu top of layouts without move content

Tags: android, android-sliding

by default jfeinstein SlidingMenu move content to view slide menu layout, but i dont like that and i want to view slide menu without move content and top of all layouts.

in this below screen shot i like number 2

[image]

Default settings are :

```
public class SlidingExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.attach);
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.content);
        // configure the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
    }

}
```

and i'm could not find whats setting view slide menu top of all layouts ans widgets after any testing `attachToActivity`

Answer (score 0):

wild guess (I don't use jFeinstein)..

when the slider activates, to remove the 'hamburger' icon from the ABar get rid of "home_as_up"...

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO |ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, 
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
```